# What mght be wrong with this queue.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm working on an appengine project in which I created a Task Queue "refresh" as defined below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queue-entries>
  <queue>
    <name>refresh</name>
    <rate>1/s</rate>
    <retry-parameters>
      <task-retry-limit>5</task-retry-limit>
      <task-age-limit>2</task-age-limit>
    </retry-parameters>
  </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

Upon deployment, I get the following error and don't know why as this definition is almost exactly the same with what is on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue

`An internal error occurred during: "Deploying xProject to Google".
XML error validatin _xProject_path_\war\WEB-INF\queue.xml against C:\Users\Oladeji\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_248562372\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.3\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.3\docs\queue.xsd`

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you show what is the queue.xsd in you local path "C:\Users\Oladeji\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_248562372\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.3\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.3\docs\"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't pass validation over the queue.xsd.

Which means the structure of the queue.xml doesn't match the structure described in the queue.xsd

Most likely the description you see on a web site and your actual queue.xsd are different.

Please, show your **actual** queue.xsd.

---

I found queue.xsd that is the same as what you have in your local path.
It puts limitation on  ([0-9]+(.?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)?)([smhd]) on 'task-age-limit.

In your case if you add s,m,h or d it will validate.

For example: 2s instead of 2 in task-age-limit tag.

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks! Now I'm wondering why Google would provide us with a queue.xsd but also give us examples that won't work with it. I guess I over-trusted them :(

Comment: Please, don't forget to accept the answer if you think it is correct, of course.

Comment: Most likely the example is outdated. It happens very often.